# Arrange MultiDimensional arrays to descending or ascending

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to arrange this multidimensional array to ascending or descending. However, I need the relation between column 1 and 2 to still be together(meaning I need the data of eg. array[0,1] and array[0,2] to be together or related in some way or another. This are my codes as of right now.

```
int[,] time = new int[5,2]{{0,4},{1,5},{5,10},{3,4},{0,2}};
var sorted = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, time.GetLength(0))
                     from y in Enumerable.Range(0, time.GetLength(1))
                     select new{
                         X = x,
                         Y = y,
                         Value = time[x,y]
                    }into point
                    orderby point.Value descending
                    select point;
```

This works but it splits all my data apart. Is there a way to sort them while keeping the relation of column 1 and 2 together?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you show us the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to store your data in a multi-dimensional array, but keep each row in the array as a separate atomic unit.  And additionally, the comparison of each "point" is by X, and then Y.

```
int[,] time = new int[5, 2] { { 0, 4 }, { 1, 5 }, { 5, 10 }, { 3, 4 }, { 0, 2 } };

var sorted = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, time.GetLength(0))
                     select new Point()
                     {
                         X = time[x,0],
                         Y = time[x,1]
                     } into point
                     orderby point.X ascending , point.Y ascending 
                     select point;

int[,] sortedTime = new int[5,2];
int index = 0;
foreach (var testPoint in sorted)
{
  Point aPoint = (Point) testPoint;
  sortedTime.SetValue(aPoint.X, index, 0);
  sortedTime.SetValue(aPoint.Y, index, 1);

  index++;
}
```

Comment: This is useful, but could I get just another help before i award the bounty? I need to store this processed var data into another multidimensional array but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I updated the code sample above to convert the set of Point objects back into a new 2D array.  This is all a bit contrived and could probably be optimized with a better understanding of the actual requirements, but should work fine for your example.

Answer (score 5):

I'm curious as to why you need a multidimensional array.  It's clear you are treating your data as a single-dimensional collection of "rows," rather than a 2-dimensional collection of "cells."

Why not simply make a [List(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), where T is some sort of [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) or custom struct?

On the surface, it seems like you're trying to use a screwdriver on a nail; make sure you're picking the right tool for the job ;)

Comment: I appreciate your great use of English words, sadly it doesn't help, and I like using arrays. So yeah.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might just be overthinking things. If you want to keep the points together, and sort by the first column, for instance, just omit the second `Enumerable.Range` and assign the values by hand:

```
int[,] time = new int[5,2]{{0,4},{1,5},{5,10},{3,4},{0,2}};
var sorted = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, time.GetLength(0))
                     select new{
                         X = time[x,0],
                         Y = time[x,1]
                    }into point
                    orderby point.X descending
                    select point;
```

As @Haxx points out, just add `, point.Y descending` to the `orderby` clause if the order of the second value is also important.

Comment: note that it won't sort the x,y combi this way. this will output {{0, 4} {0, 2}, {1, 5}, {3, 4} {5, 10}, }; when you sort ascending. (note the first 2 pairs). Not sure if that's a problem.

Comment: I see what you're getting at. Yes, it's unclear what was needed.

Comment: Also, it will output that in reverse. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I also think that one should treat this as a collection of rows since you want rows to always stay together. 
.NET has the `DataTable` type for that. E.g.

```
        int[,] time = new int[5, 2] { { 0, 4 }, { 1, 5 }, { 15, 10 }, { 3, 4 }, { 0, 2 } };

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("x", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dt.Columns.Add("y", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

        for (int i = 0; i < time.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = time[i, 0];
            dr[1] = time[i, 1];
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "x" + " " + "ASC";
        dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Note that I needed to type the table columns. Otherwise you'll get an alphabetical sort. I changed one of your numbers to 15 to demonstrate that the sort works on the integers (15>3, but alphabetically "15"<"3"). If you really want it back as a 2D array, see the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method would be to take implementation of some sorting algorithm like `Quicksort` and modify it to only use the `Compare(i, j)` and `Swap(i, j)` functions.
Then you can implement these functions for your multidimensional array and sort it in place.
Here is a working implementation:

```
    public static void Main() {
        int[,] time = new int[5, 2] { { 0, 4 }, { 1, 5 }, { 5, 10 }, { 3, 4 }, { 0, 2 } };
        DoSort(time);
    }

    public static void DoSort(int[,] data) {
        Func<int, int, int> comparer = (i, j) => {
            int s1 = Math.Sign(data[i, 0] - data[j, 0]);
            if (s1 != 0) {
                return s1;
            }
            int s2 = Math.Sign(data[i, 1] - data[j, 1]);
            return s2;
        };

        Action<int, int> swapper = (i, j) => {
            var tmp0 = data[i, 0];
            var tmp1 = data[i, 1];
            data[i, 0] = data[j, 0];
            data[i, 1] = data[j, 1];
            data[j, 0] = tmp0;
            data[j, 1] = tmp1;
        };

        int length = data.GetLength(0);
        Quicksort(comparer, swapper, 0, length - 1);
    }

    public static void Quicksort(Func<int, int, int> comparer, Action<int, int> swapper, int left, int right) {
        int i = left, j = right;
        int pivotIdx = (left + right) / 2;

        while (i <= j) {
            while (comparer(i, pivotIdx) < 0) {
                i++;
            }

            while (comparer(j, pivotIdx) > 0) {
                j--;
            }

            if (i <= j) {
                swapper(i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        // Recursive calls
        if (left < j) {
            Quicksort(comparer, swapper, left, j);
        }

        if (i < right) {
            Quicksort(comparer, swapper, i, right);
        }
    }
}
```

This code sorts the array in-place so you need no additional memory and in the end you get a sorted multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. You want to keep the items paired, e.g. want to treat {0, 4} as one pair, {1, 5} as another pair.

2. The expected result in ascending order is: {{0, 2}, {0, 4}, {1, 5}, {3, 4}, {5, 10}}.


As suggested by BTownTKD, strongly recommend to use some class/struct to represent your pair instead of using multidimensional array. You can use a list/array of either of the following:

- `Tuple<int, int>`
- `KeyValuePair<int, int>`
- your own struct IntPair, having two properties X and Y.

*This will not only help you to sort, but also to do further manipulations easily*. Use multidimensional array only if you have a very specific need to.

Here's sample code using Tuple:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> time = new List<Tuple<int, int>>(){
    new Tuple<int, int>(0,4),
    new Tuple<int, int>(1,5),
    new Tuple<int, int>(5,10),
    new Tuple<int, int>(3,4),
    new Tuple<int, int>(0,2)
};

//Sort Ascending
time.Sort((first, second) =>
    {
        var item1Compare = first.Item1.CompareTo(second.Item1);
        return item1Compare == 0 ? first.Item2.CompareTo(second.Item2) : item1Compare;
    });
//Sort Descending
/*time.Sort((first, second) =>
    {
        var item1Compare = second.Item1.CompareTo(first.Item1);
        return item1Compare == 0 ? second.Item2.CompareTo(first.Item2) : item1Compare;
    });*/
```